# Converting fractions (1/8, 3/8, 5/8, 7/8) to UTF-8 in C++

Tags: c++, utf-8

I have to display fractions using the symbols and I can't seem to be able to display these 4.
using

```
char UCP_VULGAR_FRACTION_ONE_HALF_UTF8 = L'\u00BD';
char UCP_VULGAR_FRACTION_ONE_QUARTER_UTF8 = L'\u00BC';
char UCP_VULGAR_FRACTION_THREE_QUARTERS_UTF8 = L'\u00BE';
```

I can get 1/2, 1/4 and 3/4 to display just fine (`cout<< (char)UCP_VULGAR_FRACTION_ONE_HALF_UTF8`), but doing the same for those fractions:

```
char UCP_VULGAR_FRACTION_ONE_EIGHTH_UTF8 = L'\u215B';
char UCP_VULGAR_FRACTION_THREE_EIGHTHS_UTF8 = L'\u215C';
char UCP_VULGAR_FRACTION_FIVE_EIGHTHS_UTF8 = L'\u215D';
char UCP_VULGAR_FRACTION_SEVEN_EIGHTHS_UTF8 = L'\u215E';
```

Gets me `[`, `\`, `]` and `^`. What am I doing wrong? I tried `g_unichar_to_utf8` with no success...

Comment: I think you should use the wide char instead.

Comment: utf8 does not mean the symbols are of type byte (char).

Comment: `L'...'` defines a  `wchar_t` character literal. You can't assign a `wchar_t` value to a `char` variable.  Use a `wchar_t` variable instead.  If you want a true UTF-8 literal, use `u8"..."` instead, and assign it to a `const char*` or `std::string`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `UTF-8` you need to store *multibyte* characters - characters contained in one *or more* bytes. Typically these are stored in a `std::string`:

```
std::string const UCP_VULGAR_FRACTION_ONE_EIGHTH_UTF8 = u8"\u215B";
std::string const UCP_VULGAR_FRACTION_THREE_EIGHTHS_UTF8 = u8"\u215C";
std::string const UCP_VULGAR_FRACTION_FIVE_EIGHTHS_UTF8 = u8"\u215D";
std::string const UCP_VULGAR_FRACTION_SEVEN_EIGHTHS_UTF8 = u8"\u215E";
```

Or possibly a *null terminated char array*:

```
char const* UCP_VULGAR_FRACTION_ONE_EIGHTH_UTF8 = "\u215B";
char const* UCP_VULGAR_FRACTION_THREE_EIGHTHS_UTF8 = "\u215C";
char const* UCP_VULGAR_FRACTION_FIVE_EIGHTHS_UTF8 = "\u215D";
char const* UCP_VULGAR_FRACTION_SEVEN_EIGHTHS_UTF8 = "\u215E";
```

Comment: @adinutzyc21 Then leave it out. Using `\uNNNN` should put the correct code in the string. Otherwise copy and past the actual character into the string.

Comment: I don't see any good reason to store them as `std::string` (they are constants, they don't need to grow, there's no possibility of embedded NULs) - just use `const char *`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `wchar_t` instead of `char`. Also be aware that you can't print `wchar_t` using `std::cout`, you need to use wide version of `std::cout` which is `std::wcout`. BTW, If you use `wcout` with `cout` together, the program will crash most probably. so you may want to store these unicode characters in normal UTF-8 `std::string` instead of `wchar_t`, and print them using `std::cout`